# Automatically updating Remote Server(B) Table when there is a Update in Server(A) Table with different schemas

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having an Update trigger in Server A calling a Stored Procedure on Server B(through Linked Server) to update rows in Table2 in Server B, whenever there is a update in rows in Table1 (in Server A).
The problem I am currently am facing is that it is only partially updating the values into Server B table2.
And I have no clue how the data is missing randomly while writing to the remote Table.

```
Update Trigger:
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdateTable1] ON [dbo].[Table1] 

  After UPDATE 
AS 
       declare @col1 nchar(10);
       declare @col2 nvarchar(50);
       declare @col3 nvarchar(50);
       declare @col4 nvarchar(100);
       declare @audit_action varchar(100);
       declare @lastUpdated datetime;

       select @col1=i.col1 from inserted i;  
       select @col2=i.col2 from inserted i;     
       select @col3=i.col3 from inserted i;     
       select @col4=i.col4 from inserted i;    

       SET NOCOUNT ON;
if UPDATE(col1) OR UPDATE(col2) OR UPDATE(col3) OR UPDATE(col4)   
    -- Insert statements for trigger here
       BEGIN
 exec [ServerB].[dbo].[sp_UpdateDetails_INTO_ServerB_FROM_ServerA] @col1, @col2, @col3, @col4      

END
```

Comment: You are only updating a single row with the trigger as is. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178889/sql-server-a-trigger-to-work-on-multiple-row-inserts

Comment: To put it another way, if your update affects two rows, what do you think gets assigned here: `select @col1=i.col1 from inserted i;` -- which value of `col1` gets assigned to the variable, and then passed along to the remote stored procedure? Hint: it doesn't matter, it matters that only one of them gets passed.